# Catching events DOMContentLoaded and onload using Chrome plugin for each frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, dom-events

I need to write chrome plugin to intercept events `DOMContentLoaded` or `onload` to gather statistics about the elements in each frame.

I have tried:

```
document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', onContentLoaded, false);
```

But it only works for background.html. I also tried:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript (tabId, {file: "ContentLoaded.js", allFrames: true}, null);
```

Where ContentLoaded.js create an event listener for each frame, but it did not help.

```
document.onload = contentLoaded;
```

For each frame does not work at all.
How can I catch this events for each frame?

Comment: Combine #1 and #2. Let #1 be the content of the content script which you inject at #2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob W

As I understand you mean following:

```
var stmt = "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (data){alert('onContentLoaded');}, false); alert('TEST');";
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code: stmt, allFrames: true}, null);
```

But it dose't work. I see alert 'TEST', that simply notify me about script ran, but I don't see alert 'onContentLoaded'.

Dose I understand you comment correct?